# How to run reports in sharepoint site using scheduler and email to sharepoint library?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, reports, schedule

I want to run reports in sharepoint site using scheduler and email reports output to sharepoint library.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link [Creating subscription on reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283186.aspx) to create subscription on reports which is the same thing i was searching.

Answer (score 1):

If you got [SQL Server Reporting Serivices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) instance set up, you can create reports via [Business Intelligence Development Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173745%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) that query SharePoint list data.  These reports can be scheduled to run on any schedule and the report contents emailed to specific users or AD groups or to email enabled documnt libraries.

Comment: We create reports using Report builder tool and store it on sharepoint site.Can you pls help me to schedule such reports or  powershell command to execute such reports.